# how to pass a special character as argument in c-shell

Tags: csh

```
#!/bin/csh -f
set rule = $1
echo 
echo $rule
```

and when I execute this small script as:

```
<script1.csh> "test"
test

<script1.csh> "who?"
set:No match
```

my question is how can I make "?" as a part of the argumentj in c-shell?
Thanks you very much for your help
Howard

Comment: try `"who\?"` (you may need more that one `"\"` char). Also change your script to `set rule = "$1"`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add quotes:

```
#!/bin/csh -f
set rule = "$1"
echo
echo "$rule"
```

The way variables in csh (and also the Bourne shell) work is not really the same as a regular programming language, but more as a "macro language"; that is, a variable like `$1` or `$rule` is simple replaced with the contents, rather than interpreted as a special variable.

So `set rule = $1` would be the same as if you had typed `set rule = who?`. To avoid problems you should generally *always* quote variables.

(the exact rules are a bit more complex than described above, but this is a useful way to think about it).